# BPF/Wincap filter not working in Pcap.net

Tags: vb.net, winpcap, pcap.net

I'm using a pcap.net process to broadcast out a packet, and listen in for a response. I want the response packets that it accepts to be a certain length. However, whenever I add a filter it only returns packets of length 100. Here's the code:

```
' Open the output device
Dim Communicator As PacketCommunicator = selectedOutputDevice.Open(100, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 300)

Communicator.SetFilter("len >= 300")

' send broadcast packet
Communicator.SendPacket(BuildEthernetPacket(ReqInfoPkt, "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"))

' receive packets 
While result = PacketCommunicatorReceiveResult.Ok And packetlist.Count < 500 And _
    Not result = PacketCommunicatorReceiveResult.Timeout

    result = Communicator.ReceivePacket(packet)
    packetlist.Add(packet)
End While
```

Here's a link to the screen shot: [link](http://postimg.org/image/b7d2vtrg5/) I tried asking on the pcap forums but didn't get a response.

So what am I doing wrong? Is there a synatx issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the device with the snapshot length set to 100 which means you cut all packets to be at most 100 bytes.

You should probably do

```
selectedOutputDevice.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 300)
```

instead.

See the [tutorial](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Opening%20an%20adapter%20and%20capturing%20the%20packets&referringTitle=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide).

Comment: If that is true, then how come when I have it set to 100 and no filter, I still get packets over 100 length?

Comment: Can you give some pcap files as examples for that?

Comment: Again, I don't understand what format you mean by pcap files, but here is a screenshot with a breakpoint of my list(of packets) with a 222 packet length.  [ScreenShot1](http://postimg.org/image/e4i3itwux/) and one with 416 size packets. [screenshot2](http://postimg.org/image/ns1u2wqfj/)

Comment: From this url: http://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-users/2008-September/002766.html what I understand is that if you don't specify a filter, the packet is not truncated. You can use Wireshark to save and read pcap files. You can also read and save pcap files using Pcap.Net.